# NHibernate: Handling Select() on empty result sets

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Invoking the following query when there is no `Entity` record in the database throws a `NotSupportedException`

```
var list = session.Query<Entity>()
                  .OrderBy(x => x.TranslationTime)
                  .Take(10)
                  .Select(x => x.TranslationTime)
                  .ToList();
```

Removing the `Select(x => x.TranslationTime)` makes the query be processed fine.

Is there a way to make NHibernate accept the original query even on empty result sets?

Comment: I doubt that the problem is dependent on the number of records of Entity. It certainly shouldn't be, so if that really is true, it would be good to have complete exception info to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Take(10)` method has to come after the `Select` method:

```
var list = session.Query<Entity>()
                  .OrderBy(x => x.TranslationTime)
                  .Select(x => x.TranslationTime)
                  .Take(10)
                  .ToList();
```